Pick timestamps from the secondary table which are within the interval from the first table (sqlite)
Let's assume that we have the following sqlite tables with some values (timestamps).
CREATE TABLE main_test (
   main_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   main_ts INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sec_test (
   sec_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   sec_ts INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO main_test (main_ts) VALUES(1711670399), (1711583999), (1711497599), (1711411199), (1711151999)

INSERT INTO sec_test (sec_ts) VALUES (1711500000), (1711200000)

Timestamps in these tables do not match but I need to pick timestamps from the secondary table (sec_test) which are within the timestamps interval from the first table (main_test) so the result will look in the following way:
main_id|main_ts   |sec2_ts   |
-------+----------+----------+
      1|1711670399|      NULL|
      2|1711583999|1711500000| -- 1711500000 is between 1711583999 and 1711497599
      3|1711497599|      NULL|
      4|1711411199|1711200000| -- 1711200000 is between 1711411199 and 1711151999
      5|1711151999|      NULL|

Does anyone know how to implement it? The initial tables (used in the real project) are quite big so speed is important.

The following:-
WITH
    cte_se AS (
        SELECT 
            *,
            (
                SELECT main_ts 
                FROM main_test AS mt2 
                WHERE mt1.main_ts > mt2.main_ts
                ORDER BY mt2.main_ts DESC 
                LIMIT 1
            ) AS i_end
        FROM main_test AS mt1
        ORDER BY main_ts DESC
    )
SELECT 
    *,
    (
        SELECT sec_ts 
        FROM sec_test
        WHERE sec_ts BETWEEN i_end AND main_ts
    ) AS sec_ts
FROM cte_se;

Results in:-


i_end column left in output for demonstration purpose

note this assumes only 1 row from sec_test will be in an interval


